# How to using Cloud IoT core for device (IoT record sound) and save to cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, storage, iot, google-cloud-iot

I'm a new user of the GCP and still learning. I want to ask about the concept of Cloud IoT core. So I want to make a project where an IoT device can record sound, then can send the sound to cloud storage. Can it be done using the Cloud IoT core to store sound files (.wav / mp4 / etc)?
And please give me some information on how Cloud IoT core works to save sound files from IoT devices to a storage bucket?. I've read other references, but I'm still a little confused about what to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept of Cloud IOT core:

https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/concepts/overview.

There is no clear reference available on "How Cloud IoT core works to save sound files from IoT devices to a storage bucket" ,I have compiled from several documentations and here is the possible solution:

Cloud IOT core receives sound files from IOT devices,Telemetry data is then forwarded to pubsub topic .[1]You can then use cloud functions to trigger API calls such as Speech to text and store it in GCS.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#uploading_your_transcription_results_to_a_bucket

Additional Reference(s):

[2]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRZzqpvARbc

[3]https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices?&_ga=2.88421918.-429047876.1617103817&_gac=1.219220459.1619682723.CjwKCAjwj6SEBhAOEiwAvFRuKAiGsSOqGjF8qKuFXZKzET7WHB3pOsLX2mPu14g34AXmCLFepYvixxoCuL8QAvD_BwE#creating_a_device_registry_with_multiple_pubsub_topics

Comment: Thank you for the all of reference, it means a lot :) !

Answer (score 0):

If you do not stick to these [limits and quotas](https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas), it could be hardly possible.

I think you can provide a better solution with http/s api.